# CDF for squared sum of Rayleigh random variables

Tags: chi-squared-distribution, non-central, rayleigh-distribution, complex-numbers

In short, I am looking to estimate the distribution of

$ \eta = \sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - z_i)^2$, for each $X_i \sim \text{Rayleigh}(1)$ and constants $z_i$.

If $X_i$ were Gaussian, then this could be estimated as a non-central chi-squared distribution, but with Rayleigh random variables I am stumped. Because of the relationship between Rayleigh random variables and the non-central chi-squared, I wonder if there is a way to merge both that I'm not seeing?

---

Slightly longer version:
I actually have $Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}_\mathbb{C}(0, 1)$, so measurements from a complex normal distribution, and I want to estimate a distribution of their magnitudes. This is the part where the Rayleigh distribution comes in, as, to my knowledge, $X_i \sim |Y_i|$.
Written in complex numbers, the problem is estimating the distribution of
$ \eta = \sum_{i=1}^N (|Y_i| - |z_i|)^2$, for each $Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}_\mathbb{C}(0, 1)$.

To me, this looks like the type of thing to have been extensively covered somewhere in the depths of telecommunication engineerring, but I couldn't find a reference.

Happy about any pointers :)